# Why can I not install SQL Server Express 2016 on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit SP1?

Tags: sql-server, installation, windows-7, sql-server-2016, windows-7-x64

When trying to install SQL Server 2016 Express in Windows 7 Professional x64 SP1 in VMware I get the following message.

[image: sql server 2016 express error]

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you just click on the link and go through all requirements to check which one you are not satisfying?

Comment: just read the message and take 5 mins to check requirements

Comment: If you check link that was provided you will find out that Windows 7 does not support SQL Server 2016

Comment: Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Late to the question, but SQL 2016 apparently is supported For Win 7 via LocalDB.  I had installed Visual Studio Professional 2015 and I'm assuming that the LocalDB for 2016 was installed in that process.  It may have been SQL Server Data Tools or Similar Component, but I can create localdb instances with SQL server 2016 database version (13.0.2151).  I can then connect to them via visual studio or SSMS 2016.  I'll provide a  detailed answer when I can, but If you have ..\ProgramFiles\130\Tools\Binn folder there may be SqlLocalDB.exe installed with related folders and files (A LocalDB folder).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the error message states SQL Server 2016 is not supported in Windows 7. You will have to upgrade to Windows 8 or higher or switch to a Windows Server operating system. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#pmosr) is a list of all the operating systems (and other hardware and software requirements) in which SQL Server 2016 can be installed.

Comment: So SQL Server now supports Linux but not windows 7.  Great!

Comment: Yes, it's ridiculous

Answer (score 32):

Here is a workaround for users that need SQL 2016 on a Windows 7 development PC.  This will allow the developer to develop and manage them by using using MDFs in LocalDB:

1. If you don't have Visual Studio 2015 then get it or the 2015 Community Edition
2. Download and install SQL Server Data Tools.  [SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

Note:

> When I initially installed Visual Studio 2015 I chose custom install and selected all options.  I was assisting someone else troubleshoot their installation so I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on another Win 7 Computer.  I chose custom Install and under Windows and Web Development options I chose Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools.  It stated 2012 SQL Server, but after install and restarting I had both the 2014 and 2016 SqlLocalDB (under 120 and 130 folders respectively).  SQL Server Data Tools install may not be needed unless you need SSIS, SSAS or SSRS which I do need.

After all of this you will need SQL Server Management Studio 2016 or higher to connect to the local db and access the 2016 functionality.

After you have installed this there should be a SQL Local DB command Line tool installed.  My install location was `D:\Programfiles\130\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe`

The default install location as pointed out by Discosultan may be:

```
D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe
```

My install path was different, but that may be due to the several versions and related components of SQL server that I have installed on the PC and the manner of my installs.  Once you have done the install you can search for SqlLocalDB.exe if you have multiple versions and navigate to the 2016 version,  (product version 13 in the 130 subfolder).

> You can find the install folder path in the registry for SQL 2016 by reviewing the following Registry Entry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (Abbreviated to HKLM below):

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions\13.0

You can run the command line from there or add the directory to the path statement.  I have multiple versions so I just go to the directory.  Then you create a localDB instance and start it:

`SqlLocalDB create "LocalDBExample2016" -s`

[SqlLocalDB Utility Command Line Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx)

From that point if you prefer the GUI you can open SQL server Management Studio 2016 or through Visual Studio and connect to server:

```
(localdb)\LocalDBExample2016
```

From there you can add databases, etc.

The mdf and log files will default to C:\Users\[UserName], but they can be moved when creating the databases or copied elsewhere and given to the DBAs, etc.  Some of the features won't be available like in memory OLTP tables.  Here are the edition comparisons: [Editions and Supported Features for SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

Comment: @csrowell I'm glad it worked.  I know that all of this can be addressed or worked around by VMs, but it is good to know that it can be done without needing another OS license.  We are slowly moving to to Win 10, but we still have some legacy app issues so until fixed we have to stay on Win 7.  That is why I posted the answer for other developers in the same or similar predicament.

Comment: @CharlesByrne Hi Charles, Is your work-around also possible with SSMS? I cannot install the "SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition" on my "Win7" so I wonder if I can still go ahead with the "SQL Server Management Studio".

Comment: @Joshua  Hi Joshua.  If all that you need is to query a SQL Server 2016 database on a server then you can just install the SSMS 2016 version without installing the Sql Server Data Tools.  Installing SSMS 2016 alone will not provide the SQL Local DB functionality.

Comment: @CharlesByrne Thank you. I have purchased an online course to learn (from scratch) all about `SQL`: how to create a database, how to create tables, how to script everything, etc... and it starts off by downloading the `SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition`, so I am now stuck before I even begin. If I understood you correctly, installing `SSMS 2016` alone will not let me even do the basics; e.g. creating a database, etc... Correct?

Comment: @Joshua, You can download the Sql Server 2014 Express which will have an express database instance (2014 version ) installed on your windows 7 PC  for learning.  [SQL Server 2014 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42299).  Most of the differences between the 2 versions are more under the hood.

Comment: Some additional info: connecting to a LocalDB instance through OLE DB uses provider `SQLNCLI11` instead of `SQLOLEDB`.

Comment: I initially liked this solution, but when applied, it didn't seem to work. I have installed SSDT both the stand alone version as well as the one for VS 2015 (I do have VS 2015 Prof. installed already). But no sign of SqlLocalDB.exe in any of the subfolders under the 130 folder. It is there for older SQL server version folders like 120 and 110, but not 130. Any ideas? I really would like to install 2016 on my development pc so that I can work on the new JSON features 2016 has to provide.

Comment: @Aamir That's strange.  It should have installed it.  Was there an option to check for localDB?  I can't remember.  The SSDT build I installed was back in November 2016ish (Build No 14.0.61021.0 and Localdb version 13.0.1605).  I had installed SSIS, SSRS & SSAS was well.  I will try it on a Win 7 PC (with VS2015 and SSDT) when I get home that doesn't have it.

Comment: Thank you @Charles. I gave up and have moved on to work with a SQL Server 2016 on the company network. It is slow compared to what I had installed on my PC, but gets the work done. At least I can now run storedprocs with the new JSON capabilities :)

Comment: @Aamir Sorry to hear.  It may not have been the SSDT.  It is working on my windows 7 PC at home.  When I installed VS 2015 Community Edition I chose Custom Install (Select All will work too).  Under the "Windows and Web Development" I selected Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools.  When I restarted I had C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe which is 2016 as well as a 120 folder for 2014.  This was before the SSDT install which provides additional support for SSIS, SSAS, SSRS.  You may want to update VS Profession Install and add the SQL Server Data Tools for the fix.

Comment: In my case, localdb use directory C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances for newly created databases

Comment: This is a nice workaround but note that FILESTREAM is not supported on LocalDB. Just now experienced and switched to a VM with Win 10 and SQL Server 2016 Express.

Comment: @ibram - You're right.  I just tried it.  I went to properties, then Advanced the FILESTREAM Access level and enabled it.  It was enabled, but when I tried to create a test DB with FILESTREAM it didn't work.  I got "FILESTREAM feature is not supported on user instances".  I had thought it was a SQL 2016 SP1 issue, but I don't think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but while you can't install SQL 2017 Express or 2016 Express on Windows 7, you *can* install SQL 2014 Express. This may not work for compatibility purposes if you're dealing with a newer version of SQL (although I've been able to install the non-express version of SQL 2016 and 2017 to Windows 7) but if you're supporting something that uses an older version of SQL Express (which, frankly, is likely if you don't have access to a newer OS) this should work well enough.

Comment: How did you manage to install "non-express" editions of SQL Server into Windows 7? The edition selection comes much later than the OS check.