# Unable to install SQL Server 2016 on Windows 7 SP1 x64

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, windows-7-x64

I need to install SQL Server 2016 (including Reporting Services, SQL Agent etc) on Windows 7. I know that it's not supported platform so I'm looking for a solution how to make that.

I found out the following two conversations on below topic:
[Why can I not install sql server express 2016 on windows 7 professional 64 bit SP1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432026/why-can-i-not-install-sql-server-express-2016-on-windows-7-professional-64-bit-s)

https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/06/01/sql-server-2016-hits-general-availability.aspx?m=1

I have followed the steps from 2nd one:
- Install on W10 VM,
- Copy all Program Files files from W10 to W7
- Copy REG KEY from W10 to W7 (don't know exactly which one)
- Install SSDT tools
- Install SSMS

All in all I have the following view:

[image]

Unfortunately when I'm trying to run SQL 2016 services it's not starting up.
Any step by step instruction would be very helpful.

Comment: What's the error message you get when trying to start the services? Look in the Windows Application log if you don't get an error popup.

Comment: I have been able to run SQL Server 2016 on Win7, the reason of not starting Service was because I had SQL 2014 running and it was blocking ports according to logfile. Now I'm facing issue with Reporting Services when I'm trying to start the service, something with Encryption keys I believe. I thught there's ready to implement solution, but I see no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question. SQL 2016 is not supported on Windows 7 or earlier. You have to upgrade to Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install SQL Server 2016 on Windows 7 but you can install SQL Management Studio on Windows 7 to connect to a remote server instance.

SSMS is now supported independent of the SQL installation.  As of v16, it is maintained independently and claims backwards compatibility to SQL2008.  The latest version is available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

As of this post, SSMS v17.9.1 worked on my installation of Windows 7 Pro x64 and allowed me to connect to a remote SQL2017 instance.

SSMS version 17.x or later does not support connecting to the legacy SQL Server Integration Services service. To connect to an earlier version of the legacy Integration Services, use the version of SSMS aligned with the version of SQL Server.