# VS2017 and LocalDB 2014

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, localdb

I try to explain rapidly my issue. I'm a kind of newbie about DB, but I'm trying to create a "database manager" using a Windows Form C# code in VS2017.

btn_click code is:

```
 try
 { 
     SqlConnection connDB = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + path + @";Integrated Security=True");
     connDB.Open();
     MessageBox.Show("Connection OK on DataSource=MSSQLLocalDB");
     connDB.Close();
 }
 catch 
 { 
     MessageBox.Show("Connection fail on MSSQLLocalDB!");
 }
```

Now, when I'm using Windows 10 and LocalDB 2016 all works great. When l try to run the same exe on a Win 7 with LocalDb 2014 the code give me message on the catch code.

I understand that I developed using SQL Server 2016 and Win 7 LocalDB 2014 doesn't support it.

How can I set VS2017 to use SQL Server 2014 to develop in order to allow any pc (Win 7 or Win 10) to work with LocalDB? Can you explain step by step, please?
There is any other way to develop with VS2017 and run with some "old" pc?

Comment: You should include details on the Exception that is being caught in your catch block. One way to get this is to change the block to `catch(Exception ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}`

Comment: LocalDB 2016 will run just fine on Windows 7.  Are you sure LocalDB 2014 (version 12) is installed on the Windows 7 computer?  It doesn't "come with" Windows, so if it is, it must have been installed by someone or some installer.  Also, the name associated with LocalDb is different depending on which version is installed.  Often for LocalDB 2014 it's called (localdb)\ProjectsV12 rather than (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

Comment: @nvuono: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3y76pnaamvb1je8/DB_error.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I personally installed localDB 2014 on win7 computer. I tried to install LocalDB 2016 but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Andrea - LocalDB 2016 does support Windows 7, but SQL Server 2016 (not localdb) does not.  You can install LocalDB 2016 by itself by installing SSDT, as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41466303/61164  .  Also, you can use the SqlLocalDb command for LocalDB 2014 to create an instance of whatever name you want (in your case, it would be MSSQLLocalDB)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch. Ok thanks. LocalDB 2016 works on Win 7 now...same version (13.0.2151.0) but the .exe works only on Win 10. This is the error:https://www.dropbox.com/s/e93uh21p48darjd/error_DB_08.04.2017.png?dl=0  I was thinking that I can create DB with visual studio and localdb2014 than try to use with both OS. Could it works?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem with localdb 16 in windows 7 could because your win 7 machine is 32 bit.  SQL 16 localdb is first localdb to only support 64 bit architecture.  I created a product that had to run on older machines as well and it drove me crazy.  I used command line to

'sqllocaldb create dbname version'

If you have multiple sql servers unnubg  To get versions do this

'Sqllocaldb version'

Here is a decent start to create local db command line https://youtu.be/M5DhHYQlnq8

Answer (score 0):

MSSQLLocalDB will fail to open in VS2017 on Win7 regardless of version. Use 'sqllocaldb create test' to create your testing database. To use it in VS2017, use the server explorer instead of the sql server object explorer. Right click on data connections then add a new connection. Select 'Microsoft SQL Server' as the data source, and use '(localdb)\test' as the server name. After you create it, you can flip over to the sql server object explorer and you'll see your (localdb)\test server available for use.